List of acceptable values for DefaultAttachmentEncoding parameter in SQL Server
THIS is the most relevant thread I've found on Stackoverflow to my question.
If I run EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_configure_sp;, I can see my default encoding is MIME. When I send CSV attachments, they go to the recipient with UTF-16 encoding. I've been requested to change this to UTF-18.
I understand that this stored procedure can alter encoding:
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp   
          @parameter_name = N'DefaultAttachmentEncoding',  
          @parameter_value = N'MIME'

I changed default encoding to 'UTF-8' and sysmail_help_configure_sp reflected the change, but attached files are still being sent/received as UTF-16. Same result when changing parameter to 'UTF-18'.
I cannot find a list of acceptable values for the DefaultAttachmentEncoding parameter nor can I see any change in encoding when altering the DefaultAttachmentEncoding value and sending an attachment like
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'default',
                    @recipients = 'email@email.com',
                    @subject = 'subject',
                    @body = 'hello',
                    @query = 'select * from myTable',
                    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
                    @query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv', 
                    @query_result_separator = ','

Can anyone provide a list of acceptable values and/or explain what changing DefaultAttachmentEncoding actually does? The documentation for sysmail_configure_sp doesn't provide or explain.

Do you have a real world use for UTF-18 encoding? UTF-9 and UTF-18 are essentially "joke encodings" for the few 1980s computers that were based on 36 bit memory architectures. See the April 1st specification, RFC 4042 UTF-9 and UTF-18 Efficient Transformation Formats of Unicode. Sounds like you've been asked the IT equivalent of "go find a can of black and white checker paint."

@AlwaysLearning I'm not sure how the recipient process the data we send, but I was wondering if the request was mistyped and supposed to be UTF-8 myself. So, I tested changing DefaultAttachmentEncoding to UTF-8 as well as UTF-18.  I didn't notice any difference in the emailed file either way. I can leave the file conversion burden on the recipient if needed, but was trying to wrap my head around the possibility of fulfilling the request fully within SQL server.  I'm sure they could use powershell to convert, but I wonder why this DefaultAttachmentEncoding exists if it does nothing.

Unfortunately there's no documentation I'm aware of about sysmail_configure_sp's DefaultAttachmentEncoding parameter except to say that its default value is MIME. So this is conjecture... given how SQL Server's database mail works with System.Net.Mail components and external executables I expect that this setting is more to do with the transfer encoding of mail attachments than it is to do with the character encoding of the files themselves, so I'd be inclined to try variations of MIME, Base64 and QuotedPrintable and see what changes, if any, are effected in the raw mail messages.

Actually, I just stumbled across some 3rd party documentation for sysmail_mailitems's attachment_encoding column which lists possible values as 0(MIME), 1(UUEncode), 2(BINBEX) and 3(S/MIME), so perhaps try switching between MIME, UUEncode and BINHEX to see what happens.

@AlwaysLearning I tested setting DefaultAttachmentEncoding to 'S/MIME', 'UUEncode', 'BINHEX', and 'PIZZA' getting UTF-16 as the output. SQL accepted PIZZA as a DefaultAttachmentEncoding which tells me that there is no check done to make sure a valid parameter value is being passed. I didn't notice any system or procedure errors while having PIZZA as the value. I of course changed it back to MIME after some testing. If I had a lot of reputation to spare I might place a bounty on this. There's other ways to accomplish the project which prompted my OP but I hate leaving with an unsolved mystery.

This is conjecture, but I suspect this entire DefaultAttachmentEncoding setting was something that was started by Microsoft and abandoned or left in an incomplete state.  It appears to do nothing.  The documentation from Microsoft (linked in my OP) clearly states DefaultAttachmentEncoding is 'The default encoding for e-mail attachments.' but my testing showed no changes and the documentation is vague.

BINHEX and UUEncode are quite old encoding schemes so this could also be hangovers remaining from the days when SQL Server was formerly Sybase (like datetimes 1/300th second resolution).
